# Glossy node isn't reflecting

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders

On the neck label of my Jack Daniels bottle I have the glossy node plugged in but as can be seen in the image -- it's not reflecting.

I tried adding another glossy to 'double' the glossiness but that didn't work either.

How can I make it glossy?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially what's happening is the transparency is being turned into black which will just absorb all light. So it won't reflect.

How you should go about doing this, is make a material for your decal, should be a mix of diffuse and glossy, then, using the alpha from the texture as the factor, mix that with the material for the rest of the cap.

[image]

There's just a quick example I put together. The transparent parts of the texture use "Main Material", and the opaque parts use "Decal".

Comment: No Problem, I'm glad to help :)